# Android: Scrollview stretches background image

Tags: android, android-layout

So I am trying to make my activity scrollable, and when I put my relativelayout inside a scroll view, this happens:

[image]

This is the code for the above screenshot:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="53dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gearImage"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/gearDescription_string"
            android:src="@drawable/gear" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If I take out the scrollview, it turns out right, but of course without the scrolling function which I want:

[image]

Now, is there any way I can get it to look like this:

[image]

So that I can still scroll, but if they reach the bottom of the background image I have, it's just white (hard to tell because the background of the webpage is white, but I added a white rectangle to the bottom of the second image to show what I mean). There wouldn't be a reason for them to reach the bottom anyways.

Of course, if you have any other suggestions as to how I can implement the scrollview without stretching by background image, I would be most delighted to hear about them.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason your trying to put the background inside of the scroll view, as oppose to behind it using a relative layout to hold the scrollview?

Comment: @Stevy888 Sorry, what do you mean exactly? Are you suggesting that instead of the way I have it right now (Scrollview -> RelativeLayout) try RelativeLayout -> ScrollView -> RelativeLayout Thanks!

Comment: Yes, or something along the lines of RelativeLayout->ImageView and ScrollView->RelativeLayout. The image is being stretched because it's trying to match the height of the parent (scrollview), which is larger then the screen. By putting the image outside of the ScrollView the parent is no longer the scrollview, and fill_parent will refer to the height of the screen.

Comment: @Stevy888 Okay that's cool, but there are two other problems because of that. The imageview outside the scrollview inside the outer relativelayout does not scroll with the content inside the inner relativelayout. Second, when the keyboard comes up, the imageview is resized to a small little imageview to fit in the gap between the top of the screen and top of the keyboard. I tried adding this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" without any luck. Thanks again.

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to achieve with the image and scrolling? You want the image to not be stretched but also scroll with the content?

Comment: @Stevy888 Precisely. Let me be more clear. I only need the scrolling to occur when someone is inputting text. So the view does not need to scroll until the user clicks on an EditText field. Then the view can scroll until the bottom of it hits the top of the keyboard. It works fine and exactly in this manner until I add a background image. Do you understand what I mean now? Thank you.

Comment: oh ok i think i have an idea of what you mean. To make it so the image isn't stretched and theres some coloured space below it. Create a new drawable as an xml file and add the image to is as a bitmap and add the colour into this file as well. I would suggest something like:
<layer-list>
  <item>
    coloured background
  <item/>
  <item>
    <bitmap
     android:src= yourimage/>
  </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: @Stevy888 That's an interesting solution, but the problem with that is that user will scroll and be able to see the colored space quite easily, right? I thought of another way, but it is based on something which I don't know whether it is possible or not. Is it possible inside the relativelayout to put things on top of each other? For example, can I put an imageview behind a button in the same layout? Thanks.

Comment: yes. This is one of the main reasons to use a RelativeLayout over a LinearLayout. RelativeLayout is a more expensive layout, but allows for views to be layered on top of each other and be layout up in more complicated ways.

Comment: @Stevy888 Okay, I'm going to put a new question to better explain what I need help with. I think I may be confusing everyone here with exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was that my image was too large in terms of pixels. I guess the scrollview is compelled to keep the image at its original size, so what it did was just that. It made the length the full length of the raw image because my scrollview was vertical, and squished it along the width because I didn't have a scrollview going side to side.

The simple fix was to make the image smaller. How odd that it can resize properly inside a normal layout, but not inside scrollview.

Comment: How to edit the photo size to exactly fit the scrollView background?
Does this depend on the phone resolution?

Answer (score 6):

Check out [`android:fillViewport`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport). According to the documentation, this `defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport`. Add this line of code to your `ScrollView`:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Hope this helps.

### EDIT:

Try the following:

1. on the `ScrollView` set the `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
2. on the `RelativeLayout` set the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Tried your edit, and it didn't work either. But should I have the background in the scrollview or in the relativelayout?

Comment: I'd put it on the `ScrollView`

Comment: Well the problem with that becomes that when I have a text field inside my relativelayout and I select it, then the keyboard pops up from the bottom. That's fine, but then the background image shrinks to fit in the space between the top of the screen and keyboard, and when I scroll the text fields, they scroll infront of the background and it looks weird. What I need is for everything in the relativelayout to scroll together. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Add it then as a separate `ImageView` to your layout.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, this is worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/rel"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the background to `RelativeLayout` set it to your `ScrollView`. So you just have to move this attribute from the `<RelativeLayout>` tag to `<ScrollView>` tag :

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

This will remove the stretching which is happening, and the background won't scroll with the `RelativeLayout`. But this doesn't produce the effect of showing white background below the unscaled background.

Comment: Thank, I tried that too, but it wouldn't work either. I can't understand what's wrong, it seems like it should work. If I put the background in the scrollview, should I keep the height of the scrollview to stay at fill_parent?

Comment: The thing is, if I do this, the background doesn't move when I scroll. So my text fields will scroll in front of it when I select them to enter text. I need the background and everything in the relativelayout to move together, so I think it is necessary for me to keep the background in the relativelayout.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me

Add this line to the respective activity in your manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```