# Android: Make layout scrollable when keyboard comes up

Tags: android, android-layout

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725552/android-scrollview-stretches-background-image).

Have spent days on this issue, and can't seem to get what I want. What I need very simply is this entire view to be scrollable when the keyboard pops up after touching an edittext field:

[image]

Note that this view is not scrollable, it doesn't need to be.

So when the user hits the edittext field (say the first one), it looks like this:

[image]

And if he/she chooses, the view can be scrolled to end no further that the way it looks here:

[image]

I've tried every combination of scrollview I could think of, but all it does is stretch my background image. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, but I just can't find it. I would really be grateful to anyone who can solve this problem. Here is the XML for the layout by the way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingTop="53dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="text2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="text3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="text4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gearImage3"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gearDescription_string"
        android:src="@drawable/gear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Kindly note the latter two images are not from the real app (photoshopped to show what I need) but the first one is from my app. Thanks.

Comment: I've experienced an interesting development. Just to test it out, I changed the background to ic_launcher.png ... you know, that default app icon that comes in a new eclipse project. Well, to my surprise, it works perfect! So it seems the problem has been triangulated to the drawable image in fact. Can anyone at all suggest why? I feel like I am so close to finding out what's wrong, ahhh!!

Comment: What is the file format and the size of the drawable?

Comment: @edwoollard So funny you ask that! I just figured it out, then saw your comment!! The image was too big, and that was causing the stretching. I still don't understand why though. It works just fine even with the large image without the scrollview, but as soon as U add the scrollview, it wants to stretch to the actual pixel size of the image. Any ideas why that happens? By the way, the image is a png. The funny thing is, it's only happening to some images. This is an extremely confusing matter.

Comment: When you don't use a ScrollView, it just fits the image to the one screen as it knows you don't want it to scroll (be bigger than one screen). As soon as you add in the ScrollView, it allows the drawable to stretch to it's actual size. Just make sure you always get the sizes correct. Good, png is definitely the format to use. Glad we finally sorted that problem after all of this. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ScrollView only scrolls to as far as there is data. So simply adding a ScrollView should just fix your problem. Add this to the start of your xml:

```
 <ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and then obviously add this at the bottom, after everything else:

```
 </ScrollView>
```

I use this in my app and when the keyboard shows, I can still scroll to the bottom of the page. If your fields as shown in screenshot 1, are not longer than one normal phone page, it won't scroll anyway. It will only scroll when you have the keyboard up as it can't then see the whole screen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I saw your other question. However try adding the attributes that I have listed as it works fine for me and doesn't stretch my normal view of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No dice, it didn't work. I tried this exact thing earlier too, and nothing at all works. It always stretches the view even though my fields are not longer than one page. I just don't get it :'( Any other suggestions?

Comment: I really don't understand that. I've done exactly that and it works exactly how you said you wanted it to work. Sorry, I have no idea. What Android version are you targeting etc?

Comment: That's alright, hopefully someone can chime in. This is driving me up the wall for days. I have this in my manifest:     `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11"  />`

Comment: I'm just trying anything here. Try changing 'android:layout_height' and 'android:layout_width' to 'match_parent', this is whilst still using the ScrollView.

Comment: I'm also now thinking that the weird stretching is due to your background. What exactly does that drawable contain? Is it all of the page and with the sweet etc?

Comment: I'm sure that if you remove the drawable background and just put like a plain white colour background, you would not have any problems. I'm sure it is due to your drawable background stretching oddly. Please try, just to clarify that is the cause.

Comment: Change them to match_parent in the relativelayout? I just tried that, no change. Perhaps it is due to my background, not sure. That drawable contains exactly what you see all in one .png. So that page, the candy, everything is just an image. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the drawable background, it works just fine. Well, it doesn't scroll to the end of the page, it scrolls to the end of the last item (the little gear image/the end of the relative layout) as expected. This is when the keyboard pops up. It does not scroll when the keyboard is not there. So everything works great so long as I don't include the background image drawable. Also, I tried putting the drawable in both the Scrollview and RelativeLayout, both yield the same results.

Comment: Oh ok, that's great just to clarify. I'm not sure how to progress from here. I'd probably suggest putting everything in seperately. It may be best to start off with a grey linear layout background, then make your relative layout have a cream background and give it a bit of padding around the edges, maybe about 20dp. Then add the candy as an ImageView and place it where you want. The grey shape may be a bit hard to implement although it's just the same principle.

Comment: Hmm, I actually want to use a background image instead of putting each shape separately because it will be more complex later as I use scaled vector graphics to create the background (and then export to a png of course). I'll keep at it to try and isolate the problem. If you come up with any more ideas or would like to look directly at my code, please let me know. Thanks Ed.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, it's annoying having to put everything in individually, it's just that's the immediate and definite solution. I will do. Any chance you could accept my answer as I found out the drawable was the problem? :) I'll try and have a think and assist you in the near future.

Comment: Ok, sure thing. Thanks for your help. I'll choose your answer in a bit, in case someone else wants to answer but thinks I have found a conclusive one already. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I've experienced an interesting development. Just to test it out, I changed the background to ic_launcher.png ... you know, that default app icon that comes in a new eclipse project. Well, to my surprise, it works perfect! So it seems the problem has been triangulated to the drawable image in fact. Can anyone at all suggest why? I feel like I am so close to finding out what's wrong, ahhh!!